# Why is there a separate Stack Exchange website for Wordpress?

Tags: discussion

Why does https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ have its own site? I'm not saying it's pointless; the stuff over there's invaluable. I'm just curious as to why it couldn't just go on the WordPress tag on StackOverflow, which has significantly more traffic.

Comment: It can usually go on either site.  Presumably wordpress.se also allows some not-so-programming related questions about wordpress that would be borderline off-topic on SO.  See [their  on-topic page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The same question could be raised for most of the other sites in the network (or at least, the technically oriented ones, anyway). There are similar sites for Joomla and Drupal (ie the biggest direct competitors for Wordpress) and a number of others.

Comment: Thank god there is a different site for it, if you know what I mean

Comment: Can you share statistics on "has significantly more traffic"?

Comment: @Nemo - Purely anecdotal. If I cross post a question on SO and WP.SE, the SO version will always get more views.

Comment: Ah ok. Let's see, I took your top Wordpress.SE question and a  [wordpress] SO question with same upvotes and the views/month are comparable. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168981/how-do-i-go-straight-to-edit-more-details-when-clicking-on-an-item-in-the-medi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496120/wp-enqueue-scripts-not-firing-in-wordpress Definitely worth investigating (assuming we're able to  compare questions which are equally in scope for the respective site).

Comment: The other site is not a trap! We did not create wordpress.se to tag, to alienate or isolate your kind. All we just want to help! There is no danger.. You can trust me!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My reading of it goes like this:

StackOverflow is very specifically for programming questions.

A lot of Wordpress issues are not programming problems, but down to configuration, or choosing the right plugins, or how to work with themes, etc etc.

Those sorts of questions are explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow, because it's a site for programming problems. But they are on-topic for Wordpress.stackexchange, because it's a separate site with its own rules about what is on-topic or not.

So the bottom line is that if you have a question that about problem with some code you've written for Wordpress, then it is probably on-topic for either site. But if your Wordpress question doesn't involve code that you've written, then it probably belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.

Comment: That makes sense - I think because I only tend to go to the WordPress site for programming questions, I was seeing more of a crossover than there necessarily is.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is more popular as a whole because it's more of a generalized site. It's a "catch-all" for development questions so people from all languages visit it daily. WordPress Stack Exchange is a very centralized exchange dealing specifically in WordPress development practices. The [wordpress] tag on Stack Overflow can exist in conjunction with WordPress Stack Exchange because what may be on-topic on Stack Overflow would be considered off-topic on WordPress Stack Exchange.

WordPress Stack Exchanges purpose is to help people understand how WordPress works, how it's core functions work, and how they can use those functions in their theme development or plugin development. Here you'll get the best references and quality answers from people who work with WordPress daily.

WordPress Stack Exchange is not a place for general PHP questions or questions about 3rd party plugins whose functionality lies outside the of WordPress core. Questions where you need to understand `woocommerce_content()`, which is not part of WordPress but instead part of the 3rd Party WooCommerce plugin, would be off-topic.

Stack Overflow is a place that allows **all** development questions which include asking to understand 3rd party code such as WooCommerce which is why the two sites can live in conjunction. I would also like to point out that having a site specifically to a CMS such as WordPress lessens the noise of other questions you may not care about on Stack Overflow, like an overall filter of questions specific to WordPress. Finally, you're more likely to get an answer to your WordPress questions on the site specific WordPress Stack Exchange than Stack Overflow as it seems the answer-rate for WordPress tags are below ~50%.