# What is the purpose having WordPress related Tags in SO even having WordPress Development Site?

Tags: discussion

There is a specific site in SE network for WordPress. So what is the purpose of having WordPress related Tags in SO?

Is it a bad idea move all WordPress related questions to WordPress SE Site and make WordPress as offtopic in SO?

**Update** : This is **not a duplicate question** for [Why is there a separate Stack Exchange website for Wordpress?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309587/why-is-there-a-separate-stack-exchange-website-for-wordpress) because I have already mentioned below why their answer is not valid for this question.

Similar Question : [Why is there a separate Stack Exchange website for Wordpress?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309587/why-is-there-a-separate-stack-exchange-website-for-wordpress)

Answer for that question :

> StackOverflow is very specifically for programming questions.
>
> **A lot of Wordpress issues are not programming problems, but down to
>   configuration, or choosing the right plugins, or how to work with
>   themes, etc etc.**
>
> **Those sorts of questions are explicitly off-topic for StackOverflow**,
>   because it's a site for programming problems. But they are on-topic
>   for Wordpress.stackexchange, because it's a separate site with its own
>   rules about what is on-topic or not.

But those are **off-topic** in WordPress Development site also. When writing above answer, those type of question might be on topic. But now those are also off topic in WordPress Development SE site including plugin / theme recommendation, plugin theme specific questions etc. So I don't see any different.

Comment: If WordPress.SE doesn't want the questions that are now on SO then, yes, it is a bad idea to move all WordPress tagged questions to WordPress SE

Comment: Where did you find that those config/theming questions are now off-topic on Wordpress.SE?

Comment: @Polygnome the OP already linked to that question and claims the answer there is no longer valid. So either we need to get that answer updated by a reliable source or simply answer this question.

Comment: @rene Just because OP claims its no longer valid doesn't mean that is true. I fail to see any reason in OPs question why the old Meta question does not longer apply. As long as this reason isn't clearly stated, its a duplicate and already asked and answered.

Comment: `But those are off-topic in WordPress Development site also.` where do you get that from? There's loads of questions on the WP site that wouldn't work on SO. There's plenty even on the front page right now.

Comment: I am from the wordpress stack and have no idea were does the assertion of what is off-topic there come from, they are simply not true. It is stated quite clearly here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic that "server configuration for WordPress" is on topic. hope this helps @rene. (the answer in the duplicated question is not great but IMO the question there is wrong in a way, the wordpress stack exists because SE central decided it is worth having it, so questions about the why should be directed to it I guess)

Answer (score 1):

The Wordpress.SE site came long after Stack Overflow.

As a general policy, we do not ban questions on SO just because there is a specialized sister site.

If it's a valid programming question, you can choose whether you want to ask it on the specialized site, or on the main site.

There are usually upsides and downsides to either choice. Your question will probably get more views on SO, but perhaps not answers as detailed and deep as on the specialized site. The specialized site may have a culture that is more demanding of question quality than SO. Some users may not want to join a community they're not used to. And so on and so on.

> Is it a bad idea move all WordPress related questions to WordPress SE Site and make WordPress as offtopic in SO?

Yes.

- Users who asked/answered/commented on those questions but haven't joined the WP site would not get notified about changes and responses
- The sheer volume of questions would likely cause problems on the WP site
- The ratio of unanswered questions would likely go up on the WP site as a result of the migration, arguably unfairly
- The SO questions may not fit the culture and quality requirements of the WP site